# How to produce list of all integers within two integers (minimum and maximum) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and trying to see how I can write function that will take two integers and produce a list of all integers within that range.

Here's what I have so far but no luck.

```
rangeList :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
rangeList n m
 | n == m = []
 | otherwise = n : n + (rangeList n (m-1))
```

Comment: `rangeList n m = [n .. m]`. This already exists.

Comment: Hint: `n + (rangeList n (m-1))` makes not much sense, since `rangeList n (m-1)` will produce a list, and you can not add `n` to a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `rangeList` function already exists in the `Prelude`, under the name [`enumFromTo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo).

Answer (score 5):

What you aim to accomplish already exists. If both bounds are inclusive, this is:

```
rangeList :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
rangeList n m = [n .. m]
```

or if the upperbound is exclusive, you can make use of [**`pred :: Enum a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pred):

```
rangeListExcl :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]
rangeListExcl n m = [n .. pred m]
```

The main problem with your own implementation is that `n + rangeList n (m-1)` makes not much sense, since `rangeList n (m-1)` will be a list of elements, and `n` is here an `Integer`, so you can not add these together. Even if you could doo that, it would still not work correctly, since the `rangeList n (m-1)` would make a sequence between `n` and `m-1`, by adding `n` to that result, you get a range between `2*n` and `n+m-1`. The recursion shoud increment the upperbound with one, for example with:

```
rangeListExl :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> [a]
rangeListExcl n m
    | n >= m = []
    | otherwise = n : rangeListExcl (n+1) m
```